# GetTypes from a DLL?

Tags: c#, dll

I got the following code to create a DLL :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows;

namespace Plugin
{

    public class QtObject : DependencyObject
    {
        [...]
    }

    public class Timer : DependencyObject
    {
        [...]
    }
}
```

I took the DLL and wanted to introspect it with this code :

```
var library = Assembly.LoadFrom(libraryPath);
IEnumerable<Type> types = library.GetTypes();
```

And on the second line, I got the following error :
"Unable to load one or more of the requested types. Retrieve the LoaderExceptions property for more information."

And as far as I know, I should get 2 "objects" in my Collection, corresponding to my classes no ?

Thanks in adavance for any help.

Comment: What does the `LoaderExpection` property say?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably some of the references of your dll are not referenced by the application which reads the dll.

Comment: was missing a reference yes :(
thanks to "Uwe Keim" the error told me which one !

Answer (score 0):

how about doing this .....

```
  Assembly SampleAssembly;
  SampleAssembly = Assembly.LoadFrom("c:\\Sample.Assembly.dll");
  MethodInfo Method = SampleAssembly.GetTypes()[0].GetMethod("Method1");
// Obtain a reference to the parameters collection of the MethodInfo instance.
ParameterInfo[] Params = Method.GetParameters();
// Display information about method parameters.
// Param = sParam1
//   Type = System.String
//   Position = 0
//   Optional=False
foreach (ParameterInfo Param in Params)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Param=" + Param.Name.ToString());
    Console.WriteLine("  Type=" + Param.ParameterType.ToString());
    Console.WriteLine("  Position=" + Param.Position.ToString());
    Console.WriteLine("  Optional=" + Param.IsOptional.ToString());
}
```

pls go through this link [for more info](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.assembly.gettypes.aspx)